# Nested groupby LINQ to treeview

Tags: c#, linq, treeview

i have a list in the following format:

```
List<Amortizacion> lista = new List<Amortizacion>
        {
            new Amortizacion {Fecha=Convert.ToDateTime("20/01/2012"), Idbanco=1, Nbanco="Bancomer", Idgrupo=1, Ngrupo="Jorge", Npersona="Jorge", Monto=500m},
            new Amortizacion {Fecha=Convert.ToDateTime("20/01/2012"), Idbanco=2, Nbanco="Afirme", Idgrupo=2, Ngrupo="CreaB", Npersona="Noe", Monto=200m},
            new Amortizacion {Fecha=Convert.ToDateTime("20/01/2012"), Idbanco=2, Nbanco="Afirme", Idgrupo=2, Ngrupo="CreaB", Npersona="Julio", Monto=250m},
            new Amortizacion {Fecha=Convert.ToDateTime("20/01/2012"), Idbanco=2, Nbanco="Afirme", Idgrupo=2, Ngrupo="CreaB", Npersona="Marcela", Monto=300m},
            new Amortizacion {Fecha=Convert.ToDateTime("21/01/2012"), Idbanco=1, Nbanco="Bancomer", Idgrupo=3, Ngrupo="Pedro", Npersona="Pedro", Monto=150m},
            new Amortizacion {Fecha=Convert.ToDateTime("21/01/2012"), Idbanco=1, Nbanco="Bancomer", Idgrupo=4, Ngrupo="CBI", Npersona="Juan", Monto=400m},
            new Amortizacion {Fecha=Convert.ToDateTime("21/01/2012"), Idbanco=1, Nbanco="Bancomer", Idgrupo=4, Ngrupo="CBI", Npersona="Manuel", Monto=450m},
            new Amortizacion {Fecha=Convert.ToDateTime("22/01/2012"), Idbanco=2, Nbanco="Afirme", Idgrupo=5, Ngrupo="Pepe", Npersona="Pepe", Monto=300m},
        };
```

And defined my class this way:

```
class Amortizacion
{
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public int Idgrupo { get; set; }
    public string Ngrupo { get; set; }
    public int Idbanco { get; set; }
    public string Nbanco { get; set; }
    public string Npersona { get; set; }
    public decimal Monto { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to achieve a nested groupby to display it in a treeview control. First I need to group by Fecha, then by Idbanco, and finally by Idgrupo. The result i'm looking for is something like this:

- 20/01/2012 (4) acreditados

  - Bancomer

    - Jorge 500
  - Afirme

    - CreaB 750

      - Noe 200
      - Julio 250
      - Marcela 300
- 21/01/2012 (3) acreditados

  - Bancomer

    - Pedro 150
    - CBI 850

      - Juan 400
      - Manuel 450
- 22/01/2012 (1) acreditados

  - Afirme

    - Pepe 300

Note than in 'Fecha' nodes the number between parentheses is the count of fields grouped by, and in 'Idgrupo' nodes the amount displayed is the sum of individual 'Monto'.

I have coded so far

```
var gpoFecha = lista.GroupBy(g => g.Fecha);
        int ifecha = 0;
        foreach (var fecha in gpoFecha)
        {
            TreeNode nodoFecha = new TreeNode(fecha.Key.ToString());
            treeAm.Nodes.Add(nodoFecha);
            var gpoBanco = fecha.GroupBy(gp => gp.Idbanco);
            foreach (var banco in gpoBanco)
            {
                int ibanco = 0;
                TreeNode nodoBanco = new TreeNode(banco.Key.ToString());
                treeAm.Nodes[ifecha].Nodes.Add(nodoBanco);
                var gpoGrpo = banco.GroupBy(gpo => gpo.Idgrupo);
                foreach (var cred in gpoGrpo)
                {
                    TreeNode nodoCred = new TreeNode(cred.Key.ToString());
                    treeAm.Nodes[ifecha].Nodes[ibanco].Nodes.Add(nodoCred);
                }
                ibanco++;
            }
            ifecha++;
        }
```

The problem is that my code is not working as the expected. The other problem is that I don't know how to show in my tree node not only the key but the string that defines that key (I mean IdBanco=1 must show Nbanco="Bancomer", like I show above.).

Another ineresting question: is this the most efficient way of doing it?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = from l in lista
            group l by l.Fecha into fetchaGroup
            select new
            {
                Fecha = fetchaGroup.Key,
                Count = fetchaGroup.Count()
                ,FetchaGroup = (from fg in fetchaGroup
                                   group fg by fg.Nbanco into NbancoGroup
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       Nbanco = NbancoGroup.Key,
                                       NbancoGroup = (from ng in NbancoGroup
                                                      group ng by ng.Ngrupo into NgrupoGroup
                                                      select new { Ngrupo = NgrupoGroup.Key, NgrupoGroup }
                                                    )
                                   }
                                )
            }
            ;


foreach (var g in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", g.Fecha, g.Count);

    foreach (var fg in g.FetchaGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", fg.Nbanco);

        foreach (var ng in fg.NbancoGroup)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t{0} {1}", ng.Ngrupo, ng.NgrupoGroup.Sum(ngg => ngg.Monto));

            if (ng.NgrupoGroup.Count() > 1)
            {
                foreach (var ngg in ng.NgrupoGroup)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t{0} {1}", ngg.Npersona, ngg.Monto);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelent answer, in fact what I needed. Just one question, wouldn't be nicer to group by integer than by string? (I mean Idbanco->Nbanco and Idgrupo->Ngrupo).

Comment: Probably but since you have to display the string in the result anyway, you have to extract that value either by having it in the key or doing something like ng.Ngrupo.First().Ngrupo.